Application fails to link with library linked against OpenImageIO
I have a library that uses many dependencies managed by vcpkg.  I have never had any issues until I recently added OpenImageIO.

On Windows 10 (MSVC 17.6) my library builds and links successfully, and then I am able to build an application and link my library to it.

On Ubuntu 20.04.6 (g++ 10.5.0, ld 2.34) my library builds and links successfully, but all applications fail to link against it with many errors stating an undefined reference to some boost library.


When I build my library as a static lib (on Ubuntu) it yields errors that look like the following:
/usr/bin/ld: ../../vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libOpenImageIO_d.a(imageinput.cpp.o): in function `boost::thread_specific_ptr<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::~thread_specific_ptr()':
/mnt/c/Users/cgnam/source/repos/vira/out/ubuntu/vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:61: undefined reference to `boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, void (*)(void (*)(void*), void*), void (*)(void*), void*, bool)'

Minimal Working Example:
Can be found at https://github.com/crgnam/oiio-linker-error
(Required vcpkg on your computer):

To given more details without needing the repository the file structure looks like this:
vcpkg.json
CMakeLists.txt
myapp.cpp
mylib.cpp
mylib.hpp

vcpkg.json:
{
  "name": "vira",
  "version-string": "0.8.0",
  "dependencies": [
    "openimageio"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "name": "openimageio",
      "version": "2.5.8.0#2"
    }
  ],
  "builtin-baseline": "352c108a6b6d698c09a8272d8e95fdce550ae408"
}


CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

project(example LANGUAGES CXX VERSION 0.8.0)
set(CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

include_directories(.)

# Build and link my library:
add_library(mylib STATIC mylib.cpp)
find_package(OpenImageIO CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(mylib PRIVATE OpenImageIO::OpenImageIO)

# Build and link Executable:
add_executable(myapp myapp.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE mylib)

mylib.hpp:
#ifndef MYLIB_MYLIB_HPP
#define MYLIB_MYLIB_HPP

#include <string>

namespace mylib {
    void getImageDimensions(const std::string& filepath);
};

#endif

mylib.cpp:
#include "mylib.hpp"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "OpenImageIO/imageio.h"
#include "OpenImageIO/imagebuf.h"

namespace mylib {
    void getImageDimensions(const std::string& filepath)
    {
        // Open the file:
        auto inp = OIIO::ImageInput::open(filepath);
        if (!inp) {
            throw std::runtime_error("OpenImageIO could not open: " + filepath);
        };

        const OIIO::ImageSpec& spec = inp->spec();
        int width = spec.width;
        int height = spec.height;
        int channels = spec.nchannels;

        std::cout << width << " x " << height << " x " << channels << "\n";
    };
};

myapp.cpp:
#include <string>

#include "mylib.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2) {
        const std::string& filepath = argv[1];
        mylib::getImageDimensions(filepath);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    };
};

Build with:
mkdir build;
cd build;
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<path/to/vcpkg>/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake ../
cmake --build .


Things I have already tried:

Different versions of OpenImageIO available on vcpkg (I have tried both the most recent 2.5.12 as well as 2.5.8)
Building library both as STATIC and SHARED
Setting the link interface of OpenImageIO to my library using PUBLIC instead of PRIVATE (changing source/mylib/CMakeLists.txt to use: target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC OpenImageIO::OpenImageIO))
Linking OpenImageIO directly to my application (changing source/myapp/CMakeLists.txt to use: target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE OpenImageIO::OpenImageIO mylib))

So far, everything I try still successfully builds and links the library, but fails to link the library to my executable.  (Though, everything works fine on Windows/MSVC)
EDIT:
If I install OpenImageIO using sudo apt install libopenimageio-dev, and do NOT use vcpkg, and then change the source/mylib/CMakeLists.txt to:
add_library(mylib STATIC mylib.cpp)

find_library(OIIO OpenImageIO)
target_link_libraries(mylib PRIVATE ${OIIO})

My application will successfully link to mylib and runs fine (on Ubuntu).
Does this mean that there is something wrong with vcpkg port?  Or am I misunderstanding something?  Because my expectation (as with all of the other libraries that I use) is that this shouldn't be a problem (and indeed, it isn't with my other libraries such as TBB, cpsice, etc., or on Windows).

Looks like it's missing boost thread, is that library present on the compiler command line?

I understand it is missing boost, but it shouldn't be required to manually link that with applications that do not directly require it.  It is an internal dependency only of OpenImageIO, not exposed by its public API.  Everything links correctly on Windows, as well as when compiling with OpenImageIO installed via apt instead of vcpkg.  Hence my suspicion there is an issue with vcpkg port of this library.

Have you checked the compiler command line? That's the first debugging step

The error message you got because you link with OpenImageIO as static library, but doesn't link with Boost, which functions are used in OpenImageIO. One would expect that imported target OpenImageIO::OpenImageIO already contains linkage with Boost libraries, but most CMake projects don't create such linkage in their installed config files. I guess that all you successful attempts use shared variant of OpenImageIO: unlike to a static, a shared library file itself contains list of all dependent libraries.

@Tsyvarev if OpenImageIO::OpenImageIO genuinely isn't linking to the boost static libraries then that's a bug in vcpkg, it definitely should work. most CMake projects don't create such linkage in their installed config files then these projects are buggy, every library I've used links to its dependencies

@AlanBirtles: "if OpenImageIO::OpenImageIO genuinely isn't linking to the boost static libraries then that's a bug in vcpkg" - as far as I understand vcpkg spirit, in case of libraries provided with CMake projects it justs builds (and installs) those project via CMake. So, if something is not covered by the library's CMake project, then it won't be covered by vcpkg.

@Tsyvarev i think they do provide their own config files, whether they do or not the OIIO config files do correctly link to boost

@AlanBirtles unfortunately I'm unable to check that this morning.  I will check when I am back at my computer this evening.  I apologize for the confusion on my part

@Tsyvarev that is not my understanding of vcpkg, and it has not been my experience with any other package.  This is the package giving me this sort of problem

It turns out it was a problem with the vcpkg port.  The newly added version 2.5.12.0#2 fixes the issue

The newly added version 2.5.12.0#2 fixes the issue.
See: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/39533
